# How can make googletest to print the whole trace when the expect fails at subroutine

Tags: googletest

My googletest has the following structure:

```
void
check(Arg a1, Arg a2)
{
   EXPECT_TRUE(a1 == a2);
}

TEST(s, t)
{
   a1 = make_arg1();
   a2 = make_arg2();
   check(a1, a2);

   a11 = make_arg1();
   a22 = make_arg2();
   check(a11, a22);

   ...... many other check() calls ......
}
```

Now when there is test failure, the error printout just shows the source code line of check(), not the line of TEST().

The only solution I am aware of is to use SCOPED_TRACE, something like this:

```
TEST(s, t)
{
   SCOPED_TRACE("100");
   a1 = make_arg1();
   a2 = make_arg2();
   check(a1, a2);

   SCOPED_TRACE("200");
   a11 = make_arg1();
   a22 = make_arg2();
   check(a11, a22);

   ...... many other check() calls ......
}
```

But it is kind of tedious to add all the SCOPED_TRACE, is there a better solution here?

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use `EXPECT_EQ` than `EXPECT_TRUE` if you check for equality. If your `check()` only consists of this one line, then don't use a function and just use `EXPECT_EQ` inside the test.

If your `check()` function is more complex and you don't want to copy & paste, you can always use a macro instead of a function.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably write a macro that wraps the call to `check` to add a `SCOPED_TRACE`. Also, I think the way you are currently using `SCOPED_TRACE` may add to the trace for each instance.

Maybe try something like:

```
#define CHECK(msg, ...) \
do { SCOPED_TRACE(msg); check(__VA_ARGS__); } while(0)
```

You can also replace the `msg` with `""` if you just want the line number and don't need extra information.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `EXPECT_THAT` and matchers from gMock as authors [suggest](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/3b49be074d5c1340eeb447e6a8e78427051e675a/docs/advanced.md#using-assertions-in-sub-routines).

Comment: How would these address the question asked?

Comment: @underscore_d, instead of checking for a complex condition inside a subroutine, one can build a matcher for the aforementioned condition. This will move the location of the error back to the relevant line of code.